Why is the SWAP instruction missing in Python 3.11's disassembled bytecode for tuple swaps?
In newer versions, ROT_TWO is replaced by SWAP.
However, after disassembling the function using dis.dis(), I noticed that SWAP does not appear in the bytecode.
Python 3.9.0
>>> import dis
>>> def foo(a, b):
...     a, b = b, a
...
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              4 ROT_TWO
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              8 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
>>>


Python 3.11.0
>>> import dis
>>> def foo(a, b):
...     a, b = b, a
...
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
              8 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
>>>


Further Reading:
How does swapping of members in tuples (a,b)=(b,a) work internally?

one thing to notice is that in 3.9.0, it stores to a then b, but in 3.11.0 it stores to b then a. From the answer on the linked page, "The rotation is needed because Python guarantees that assignments in a target list on the left-hand side are done from left to right.", it's possible that Python might be able to optimize something about knowing that the left side of the tuple in the expression has no side-effects

If your assignment targets have any possible side-effect (which I believe in practice means "anything other than a simple variable assignment"), then you will see the SWAP opcode used in 3.11 in order to guarantee the order of side effects.  Try x[0],x[1] = a, b, for example.

In the case of simple variable assignments like a, b = b, a, why doesn't Python 3.11 need SWAP to ensure the left-to-right order of assignments?

Because the order of assignments isn't actually observable in that case, so there's no need to ensure it.
